# Restoring old WP install, renamed wp-content... restoring upload links?

Tags: php, wordpress

Expertise level: medium-low; I'm not afraid to find a file and edit it, but I don't really understand the inner workings of PHP.

I'm trying to restore a WP blog from backup, but with a fresh 3.7.1 install and a lot more attention to security after a hacking incident. Among other things, I've used [Better WP Security](http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) to rename the wp-content folder.

My steps were:

1. Install 3.7.1,
2. Import the database,
3. Activate Better WP Security, rename wp-content,
4. Pull the old theme into the themes folder.

The database restore went fine, and the site is about 90% there, but nothing that linked to the old uploads folder in wp-content is linking now.

I've searched and replaced all of the instances of wp-content on the site using an FTP program and Sublime Text, but I'm still not getting any re-linking. Images are still being sought with generated HTML that looks for things like http://foo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/pants.jpg.

Where else do I need to look for and replace wp-content to the new content folder name? I've tried poking around in the database but I have no idea where to look or what to look for.

Comment: The `SQL DB` of course with phpmyadmin...

Comment: I truly suggest you to fist install wp on a normal default install, and only later on do those changes . since you are also upgrading - some other DB changes can be present ( you did not specify from which DB you are moving.. ) It is a bad practice to do both operations at one go .. especially when upgrading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used Better WP Security, but if you need to update references to `wp-content` in the database, the best way to update the database is the [Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) mentioned in [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).  *Don't just try updating the database manually* - if the fields contain PHP serialized data (a lot of them do) you'll break things.

Sounds like you already have a database backup, so you should be safe just to give the script a try.  The search and replace values will depend on how Better WP Security works, but if the directory is just renamed (to, say, `newname`), using `/wp-content/` and `/newname/` should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress saves the attachments URL in the database so you have to replace the image paths in the sql dump  (you can use [sed](http://nixmash.com/linux/updating-mysql-content-with-sed-in-linux-mint/) ).
You don't have to touch the wordpress core and in the wordpress themes the attachments won't show in the htmls cause were called by wordpress functions.
You can make this

- Unzip wordpress in a directory
- Make the string replacement (with your new domain) in your old dump sql
- import the sql dump
- install wordpress with your mysql data and the same db prefix in the backup (it should say that there's already a wordpress installation)

That should work

Comment: "make string replacement" is not a simple search/replace, see Hobo's answer.